# Haskell QuickCheck2 using ByteString?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

The RWH books says that to get ByteString support, I need to add:

```
instance Arbitrary B.ByteString where
    arbitrary   = fmap B.pack arbitrary
    coarbitrary = coarbitrary . B.unpack
```

But my GHC 7.2 with QuickCheck 2.4.1.1 tells me:

```
`coarbitrary' is not a (visible) method of class `Arbitrary'
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`coarbitrary` has moved to it's own typeclass `CoAbritary` in QC 2.0, so simply just remove the equation for `coarbitrary`.

Also see the latest [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#t%3aArbitrary).

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid the latest API documentation hasn't helped me much. It is all mumbo-jumbo without some higher level context. A lot of other documentation is also out of date. Very curious for what is supposedly a very popular test package.