# How to get Haskell QuickCheck 2.4 to increase # tests?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Okay, as I learned via my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113751/haskell-quickcheck2-using-bytestring), the RWH book is already out of date for QuickCheck. And despite all the posts I've read that tell me how incredibly simple it is to use QuickCheck, I cannot find any place that tells me how to change the number of tests to run for a property.

RWH says:

```
handyCheck limit = check defaultConfig {
                     configMaxTest = limit
                   , configEvery   = \_ _ -> ""
                   }
```

How to do this with QuickCheck 2.4? More importantly, how would I have found out myself? Please don't tell me that I should've been able to figure it out from the API documentation.

Comment: RWH came out at a perfectly wrong time.  For example: QC changed, exceptions changed, enumerators became popular, etc.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
quickCheckWith stdArgs { maxSuccess = 5000 } someProp
```

**How I found out**

1. I went to the [API documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.1.1/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html).
2. The 2nd thing I saw, after `quickCheck` was the `Args` type with a `maxSuccess` field.
3. I didn't want to write all the fields, so I looked for a value of type `Args` - finding `stdArgs`. (Use your browsers search function - ctrl-f usually).  OTOH, I could have used [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Args%20%2bquickcheck).
4. I needed to use my `Args` type somewhere so I kept looking.  The next line was `quickCheckWith` - bingo!  On the other hand, I could have used [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Args%20-%3E%20Bool%20-%3E%20IO%20%28%29%20%2bquickcheck).

**How Else Can You Find Out**

As I stated above, you could have used hoogle to find a lot of the functions, assuming you realize the `Args` type is the core of what you need (from the haddocks).

Otherwise, you are probably reduced to looking at what other packages do, which means you need to know what other packages are worth looking at.  The [examples](http://code.haskell.org/QuickCheck/stable/examples/) folder in QuickCheck seems obvious, but not all packages include such examples.  Using [reverse dependencies](http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse) you can often find *a package* to look at, but for QC lots of packages don't have explicit dependencies.

Comment: Hi Thomas. I can appreciate that you were able to find out via the API. But I'm not yet initiated into this package, and I can't make heads or tails of most of it. Lost on Arbitrary. Way lost on CoArbitrary. Gen? No idea what that is either. The documentation says "random generator". I hope you understand what I mean. But thanks for providing a quick answer.

Comment: @Ana Understandable that you're lost on Arbitrary, CoArbitrary and whatnot. The trick is, don't be too intimidated by such stuff. Most APIs have an easy part that gets you started, so try to ignore the complicated stuff and find the easy part first. In this case, you want to _check_ your code, so search for functions containing 'check' in their name (case insensitive because of camelCase), and see what looks useful.

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to run all tests at once and provide their configuration:

```
return []
main = $forAllProperties (quickCheckWithResult stdArgs { maxSuccess = 500 })
```

Comment: thank you for this answer - quickcheck is either complicated or lacking in documenation. i did all the finding described above and did stdArgs { maxSize = 500 } which did reduced the number of samples; i did misundestanding the documentation.