# Control number of QuickCheck test cases from DocTest

Tags: haskell, doctest, quickcheck

Is it possible to control the number of cases generated by QuickCheck when running doctest?

For example you can do this when running QuickCheck from your haskell code ([see here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116262/how-to-get-haskell-quickcheck-2-4-to-increase-tests)) using the maxSuccess parameter.

However how do you do this when running doctest from the command line?

Comment: I have decided to not use DocTest to run QuickCheck now, but instead to import Test.QuickCheck.All and use the $quickCheckAll template. Not only does it solve this problem, but it also means I can have my tests type checked by ghc-mod. It was annoying having the test as a comment then realising I made a typing mistake only when I ran the test.