# How to use ByteStrings with QuickTest in DocTest?

Tags: haskell, doctest, quickcheck

How do I define the `Arbitrary` instance (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113751/haskell-quickcheck2-using-bytestring)) when using doctest and quickcheck?

Doctest and Cabal are set up as described [here](https://github.com/sol/doctest-haskell#cabal-integration) with a separate directory for tests.

The doctest line looks like this:

```
-- prop> (\s -> (decode . encode $ s == s)) :: ByteString -> Bool
decode :: ByteString -> ByteString
encode :: ByteString -> ByteString
```

Where and how do I define the `Arbitrary` instance, so that doctest can find it?
Note that I would want to define it in the test project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
-- $setup
-- >>> import Control.Applicative
-- >>> import qualified Data.ByteString as ByteString
-- >>> import Test.QuickCheck
-- >>> instance Arbitrary ByteString where arbitrary = ByteString.pack <$> arbitrary
-- >>> instance CoArbitrary ByteString where coarbitrary = coarbitrary . ByteString.unpack

-- |
-- prop> \ s -> (decode . encode) s == s
decode:: ByteString -> ByteString
encode :: ByteString -> ByteString
```

Named chunks can be used for such definitions.  However, each complete definition must be on one line, and doctest will report each use of `>>>` as a success or failure - so in this case, 6 attempts will be reported, even though only 1 of them is actually a test.

Comment: The problem with that is that I don't necessarily want the quickcheck dependency on the main project.

Comment: The `QuickCheck` dependency should only be in the test-suite.

Comment: Ah ... I overlooked the `$setup` at the top. This works fine, thanks!

Comment: At least I thought so when I read `PASS` ... Now I have included the chunk in `test/Doctests.hs` (see doctest page linked above). But this doesn't import the instances in files in the main src folder.

Comment: Do you need to have the `Arbitrary` instances for use in non-test modules?

Comment: nope ... i guess there is no reason for that (except for doctest of course) ... i prepared a minimal project for the problem: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2359191/DTT.tar.gz (you may need cabal-dev to build it)

Comment: I am not being clear.  Everything I listed in my answer should be used verbatim.  The `$setup` block should be in the actual module containing the `prop>` line.  The instances will only be in scope for that module's doctests, and not any regular code in that module.  The main library or executable WILL NOT require a QuickCheck dependency.  The doctest test-suite WILL.

Comment: Another example is given at https://github.com/sol/doctest-haskell#quickcheck-properties